# Como calcular porcentaje en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

como podría generar nuevo campo "porcentaje", lo que pasa es que conectare el mysql con el php y quiero hacer esta operación desde el php haciendo el **script** como un campo temporal.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En las reglas de normalización de base de datos, los valores calculados no se deben almacenar.

Comment: Por que mejor no haces un procedimiento almacenado PL/SQL que cuando ejecutes el script llamándolo desde PHP lo puedas recorrer y hacer los campos dinamicamente desde tu PHP sin necesidad de crear un campo en la base de datos.

Comment: Si, he hecho algunos procedimientos almacenados con MySQL Workbench.

Comment: si lo haces de php, no necesitas crear un campo temporal, bastara con una variable que entregue la operación en el bucle que estas ejecutando para mostrar el porcentaje, por lo que veo el total de cantidad es tu 100%, tendrás que hacer una consulta antes para saber la cantidad SELECT SUM(cantidad) y asignarlo a una variable total y con esta hacer el calculo en php cantidad*100/total.

Comment: De hecho usando javascript este procedimiento sería mas sencillo aún, porque se calcularía en la maquina cliente liberando al servidor de  realizar dicho calculo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculas el total con una subquery, redondeas a 2 decimales y concatenas el `%` :

```
    CREATE TABLE Frutas
        (`nombre` varchar(8), `cantidad` int)
    ;
        
    INSERT INTO Frutas
        (`nombre`, `cantidad`)
    VALUES
        ('manzanas', 5),
        ('plátano', 1),
        ('uva', 1),
        ('mango', 1)
    ;


    SELECT
     nombre, cantidad,
     CONCAT( 
       ROUND(
         ( cantidad / ( SELECT SUM( cantidad ) FROM Frutas ) * 100 ),
         2 
       ), '%'
     ) AS porcentaje
    FROM
     Frutas
    ;
    

| nombre   | cantidad | porcentaje |
| -------- | -------- | ---------- |
| manzanas | 5        | 62.50%     |
| plátano  | 1        | 12.50%     |
| uva      | 1        | 12.50%     |
| mango    | 1        | 12.50%     |
```

Edit:
Un cross join pareciera ser mas eficiente:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Frutas;
CREATE TABLE Frutas
        (`nombre` varchar(8), `cantidad` int)
    ;
        
    INSERT INTO Frutas
        (`nombre`, `cantidad`)
    VALUES
        ('manzanas', 5),
        ('plátano', 1),
        ('uva', 1),
        ('mango', 1)
    ;


/* https://stackoverflow.com/a/42516348/1423096 */
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_loop_test;
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_loop_test()
BEGIN
  DECLARE int_val INT DEFAULT 0;
  test_loop : LOOP
      IF (int_val = 3000) THEN
      LEAVE test_loop;
    END IF;
   INSERT INTO `Frutas`(`nombre`, `cantidad`) VALUES
   ('otra', RAND() * (6)+1) ;
    SET int_val = int_val +1;
  END LOOP; 
END;


call proc_loop_test;

EXPLAIN EXTENDED  SELECT
     nombre, cantidad,
     CONCAT( 
       ROUND(
         ( cantidad / ( SELECT SUM( cantidad ) FROM Frutas ) * 100 ),
         2 
       ), '%'
     ) AS porcentaje
    FROM
     Frutas
    ;

SHOW WARNINGS;

call proc_loop_test;
    
EXPLAIN EXTENDED  SELECT
     nombre, cantidad,
     CONCAT( 
       ROUND(
         ( cantidad / F2.totalFrutas * 100 ),
         2 
       ), '%'
     ) AS porcentaje
    FROM
     Frutas
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT SUM( cantidad ) as totalFrutas FROM Frutas ) F2
    ;
    
SHOW WARNINGS;
call proc_loop_test;
    
EXPLAIN EXTENDED  SELECT
     nombre, cantidad,
     CONCAT( 
       ROUND(
         ( cantidad / F2.totalFrutas * 100 ),
         2 
       ), '%'
     ) AS porcentaje
    FROM
     Frutas
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT SUM( cantidad ) as totalFrutas FROM Frutas ) F2
    ;
    
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

```
    id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   1   PRIMARY Frutas  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3004    100 NULL
2   2   SUBQUERY    Frutas  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3004    100 NULL

    Level   Code    Message
1   Warning 1681    'EXTENDED' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2   Note    1003    /* select#1 */ select `rextester`.`frutas`.`nombre` AS `nombre`,`rextester`.`frutas`.`cantidad` AS `cantidad`,concat(round(((`rextester`.`frutas`.`cantidad` / (/* select#2 */ select sum(`rextester`.`frutas`.`cantidad`) from `rextester`.`frutas`)) * 100),2),'%') AS `porcentaje` from `rextester`.`frutas`

    id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   1   PRIMARY <derived2>  NULL    system  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   100 NULL
2   1   PRIMARY Frutas  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6004    100 NULL
3   2   DERIVED Frutas  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6004    100 NULL

    Level   Code    Message
1   Warning 1681    'EXTENDED' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2   Note    1003    /* select#1 */ select `rextester`.`frutas`.`nombre` AS `nombre`,`rextester`.`frutas`.`cantidad` AS `cantidad`,concat(round(((`rextester`.`frutas`.`cantidad` / '24296') * 100),2),'%') AS `porcentaje` from `rextester`.`frutas`

    id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   1   PRIMARY <derived2>  NULL    system  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   100 NULL
2   1   PRIMARY Frutas  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    9004    100 NULL
3   2   DERIVED Frutas  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    9004    100 NULL

    Level   Code    Message
1   Warning 1681    'EXTENDED' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2   Note    1003    /* select#1 */ select `rextester`.`frutas`.`nombre` AS `nombre`,`rextester`.`frutas`.`cantidad` AS `cantidad`,concat(round(((`rextester`.`frutas`.`cantidad` / '36404') * 100),2),'%') AS `porcentaje` from `rextester`.`frutas`
```

En el segundo y tercer explain se ve que el optimizador reemplaza el resultado del cross join con el valor total.

El query quedaría:

```
SELECT
  nombre, cantidad,
  CONCAT( 
    ROUND(
      ( cantidad / F2.totalFrutas * 100 ),
      2 
    ), '%'
  ) AS porcentaje
FROM
  Frutas
CROSS JOIN
  ( SELECT SUM( cantidad ) as totalFrutas FROM Frutas ) F2
;
```

el loop para agregar random values https://rextester.com/SAJXX26044 by [@eoins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6005451/eoins) sale de [una respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42516348/1423096) con [créditos adicionales de dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/62812/152074)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta alo Malbarez, pero al ejecutarlo me sale en 0% todos.

Comment: Listo, lo convertí y salio, adjunto mi cambio:
SELECT
     nombre, cantidad,
     CONCAT( ROUND(( CAST(cantidad AS float) / ( SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM Frutas  ) * 100 ),2), '%') AS porcentaje
    FROM
     Frutas

Comment: Solo una acotación: SELECT SUM( cantidad ) FROM Frutas ) * 100, por cada registro hará esa subquery, no me parece muy eficiente.

Comment: @RobertoPaillao la verdad habría que revisar el plan que arma el server, yo confiaría en que lo cachea al ser parte de la misma sesión, de última ver cómo reacciona con un cross join por ejemplo

Comment: @aloMalbarez habría que ver si alguien tiene el dato especifico con respecto a MySQL lo único que podemos hacer es especular ante la ausencia de ese dato, pero en la lógica que es lo que se ve esta clara la ineficiencia de la consulta ahora si es para contar 8 frutas no tiene importancia, pero habría que hacer el alcance para que los programadores del futuro, los que nos reemplazaran hagan bien el trabajo cuando se trate de trabajar con millones de registros, pero en fin ,mejor pasarle el proceso al cliente para algo tan trivial.

Comment: @RobertoPaillao agregado un par de ejemplos con 3000, 6000 y 9000 random values . el cross join pareciera estar siendo mejor optimizado que el subquery

Comment: Tienes razón, pero en mis pruebas las diferencias fueron marginales, pero te doy el voto, gracias por el procedimiento me servirá para hacer algunos test.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno si se trata de rizar el rizo yo también traigo mi propuesta la que consta de 2 partes, según lo que yo pensaba sería mas eficiente pero luego de los análisis resulto que estaba completamente equivocado, pero dejo mi desarrollo para que lo analicen, mi propuesta es usar una variable en la consulta de MySQL la cual se hace mediante el uso de SET @variable:=(SELECT....) y luego de eso usar dicha variable en la consulta final.

```
SET @total := (SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM Frutas);
SELECT 
   nombre,cantidad,
   CONCAT(ROUND((cantidad / @total * 100), 2), '%') AS porcentaje
 FROM
Frutas;
```

Luego de realizar las consultas usando el procedimiento citado por @aloMalbarez inserte gran cantidad de registros en mi base de prueba llegando a los siguientes valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En conclusión CROSS JOIN resulto ser el método mas eficiente, pero no tanto como para desmarcarse de la SUBQUERY , mi propuesta resulto ser la peor de todas ya que si bien la consulta resulta ser la mas eficiente de todas, ésta depende de la asignación de la variable, tiempos que hay que sumar al proceso total y según como van aumentando la cantidad de registros este tiempo es el que mas aumenta.