# MULTIPLICAR EN SENTENCIA CASE IF SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Buenas me gustaría saber como podría multiplicar el salario de los empleados mas el porcentaje introducido del siguiente código SQL dentro de las sentencias 'when', estoy calentandome la cabeza pero no lo consigo, que es lo que tengo mal?, con un sum() tampoco me funciona, lo he intentado

```
do $$
declare
  selected_emp emp%rowtype;
  input_emp_id emp.empno%type := 7369;
begin  
  select * from emp
  into selected_emp
  where empno = input_emp_id;
if found then
       case selected_emp.empname
       when 'JONES' then
                  (selected_emp.sal*0.50);
  when 'BLAKE' then
                  (selected_emp.sal*0.70);
       when 'CLARK' then
                  (selected_emp.sal*0.100);
       else
           (selected_emp.sal*0.20);
  end case;
    raise notice 'Se ha aumentado el salario del empleado % ',selected_emp.empname;  
end if;
end; $$
```

ERROR: syntax error at or near "*" LINE 12: selected_emp.sal* *0.50; ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 268

Comment: Pues seguramente se deba realizar mediante alguna formula como la de esta [web](https://es.wikihow.com/averiguar-el-porcentaje-de-un-aumento-salarial)

Comment: tambien hay una [pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/371967/como-calcular-porcentaje-en-mysql) y [mas pagina](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/SQL/1591668-como-calcular-porcentaje.html)

Comment: El problema es que me está sacando error al ejecutar el código diciendome que el calculo está mal

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido resolver el problema. Había que definir la variable selected_emp.sal para que se aplique por el porcentaje realizado. a continuación dejo el código correcto.

```
    do $$
declare
  selected_emp emp%rowtype;
  input_emp_id emp.empno%type := 7369;
begin  
  select * from emp
  into selected_emp
  where empno = input_emp_id;
if found then
       case selected_emp.empname
       when 'JONES' then
                  selected_emp.sal =selected_emp.sal*0.50;
 
  when 'BLAKE' then
                  selected_emp.sal =selected_emp.sal*0.70;
       when 'CLARK' then
                  selected_emp.sal=selected_emp.sal*0.100;
       else
           selected_emp.sal=selected_emp.sal*0.20;
  end case;
    raise notice 'Se ha aumentado el salario del empleado % ',selected_emp.empname;  
end if;
end; $$
```